# Tasty pie multipart post integer field become array

Tags: django, upload, tastypie

I uploading lie with additional fields to DJANGO testy pie and get validation error

If I post file field and char field - char field become from 'test' to '[test]'

If I post also integer field for example 57 it becomes ['57']

I check fron - it's ok

In back request.POST have converted data... Field in model described as small integer field

```
class SpkPhotoResource(ModelResource):

   img = fields.FileField(attribute="filename", null=True, blank=True)

   class Meta:
    queryset = SpkPhoto.objects.all()
    validation = CleanedDataFormValidation(form_class=forms.SpkPhotoForm)
    ...

   def dehydrate_img(self, bundle):
    return repr(bundle.obj.filename.name)

   def deserialize(self, request, data, format=None):
    if format is None:
        format = request.META.get('CONTENT_TYPE','application/json')
    if format == 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded':
        return request.POST
    elif format.startswith('multipart'):
        data = request.POST.copy()
        data.update(request.FILES)
        return data
    return super(SpkPhotoResource, self).deserialize(request, data, format)
```

//model:

```
class SpkPhoto(models.Model):
    ....
    filename = models.ImageField(db_column='FILENAME', max_length=256, upload_to=getFilePath, null=False, blank=False)
    site_order = models.SmallIntegerField(db_column='SITE_ORDER', blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        ...


def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    p = str('media/OFFICE/' + str(self.spk_propertyid.office.id))
    self.filename.storage = FileSystemStorage(location = p )

    if not self.spk_photoid:
        self.spk_photoid = get12charid_spk_photoid()

    super(SpkPhoto, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

def delete(self, *args, **kwargs):
    p = str('media/OFFICE/' + str(self.spk_propertyid.office.id))
    self.filename.storage = FileSystemStorage(location = p )
    self.filename.delete()
    super(SpkPhoto, self).delete(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Show your code.

Answer (score 0):

FormData multipart -Ajax-post- DJANGO-tastie-deserialize data in querydict is as array so just remake returned data from deserialize make it ok

```
def deserialize(self, request, data, format=None):
    if format is None:
        format = request.META.get('CONTENT_TYPE','application/json')
    if format == 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded':
        return request.POST
    elif format.startswith('multipart'):
        data = request.POST.copy()
        data.update(request.FILES)

        data2 = {}
        for name, value in data.items():
            data2[name] = value
        return data2

    return super(SpkPhotoResource, self).deserialize(request, data, format)
```